# Change a specific permission in a role, discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to disable the permission mention_everyone for every role in the server.
I've tried 2 things:

```
@client.command()
async def removeper(ctx):
        roles=ctx.guild.roles
        perms=discord.Permissions()
        perms.update(mention_everyone=False)
        for role in roles:
            print(role)
            try:
               await role.edit(permissions=perms)
            except:
                print("can't")
                continue
```

The problem here is that instead of only disabling the mention_everyone permission, it disables every permission.

```
@client.command()
async def removeper(ctx):
        roles=ctx.guild.roles
        perms=discord.PermissionOverwrite(mention_everyone=False)
        for role in roles:
            print(role)
            try:
                await role.edit(overwrite=perms)
            except:
                print("can't")
                continue
```

I didn't really understand what PermissionOverwrite() does and apparently neither did i understand Permissions(). So this code doesn't change even one permission.

Is there a way to only disable one permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the permissions of the current role, then update those permissions and set them.

```
@client.command()
async def removeper(ctx):
        roles=ctx.guild.roles
        for role in roles:
            perms=role.permissions
            perms.update(mention_everyone=False)
            print(role)
            try:
               await role.edit(permissions=perms)
            except:
                print("can't")
                continue
```